# Removing nodes causes retain cycles

Tags: swift, scenekit

In my scenekit game, nodes are added to the scene at random. These nodes travel in one direction until they've gone past the desired end position, then they will be removed. They can travel up, down, left and right. (I use `node.runAction(SCNAction.repeatActionForever(SCNAction.moveBy(...`)

Below is what I used to detect when a node has gone past its end position so they can be removed.

The problem I am having is, although this works, for some reason it is causing a retain cycle with **SCNActionMove** and **SCNActionRepeat**.

I have found that the only way to avoid this is to remove all the nodes at once in a for loop after the game is over, but this isn't ideal as the game can be played for a long time.

Thanks!

```
func renderer(renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: NSTimeInterval) {

    // If any nodes have been spawned
    if spawnedNodeArray.count > 0 {

        // Get the first spawned node
        let node = rootNode.childNodeWithName(spawnedNodeArray[0].nodeName, recursively: true)!

        // If node is moving RIGHT, check if node has reached end position
        if spawnedNodeArray[0].Direction == "RIGHT" {
            // If node has reached past end position...
            if node.position.x >= Float(spawnedNodeArray[0].EndXPos) {
                node.removeAllActions()
                node.removeFromParentNode()
                spawnedNodeArray.removeAtIndex(0)
            }
        }

        // If node is moving LEFT, check if node has reached end position
        else if spawnedNodeArray[0].Direction == "LEFT" {
            // If node has reached past end position...
            if node.position.x <= Float(spawnedNodeArray[0].EndXPos) {
                node.removeAllActions()
                node.removeFromParentNode()
                spawnedNodeArray.removeAtIndex(0)
            }
        }

        // If node is moving DOWN, check if node has reached end position
        else if spawnedNodeArray[0].Direction == "DOWN" {
            // If node has reached past end position...
            if node.position.z >= Float(spawnedNodeArray[0].EndZPos) {
                node.removeAllActions()
                node.removeFromParentNode()
                spawnedNodeArray.removeAtIndex(0)
            }
        }

        // If node is moving UP, check if node has reached end position
        else if spawnedNodeArray[0].Direction == "UP" {
            // If node has reached past end position...
            if node.position.z <= Float(spawnedNodeArray[0].EndZPos) {
                node.removeAllActions()
                node.removeFromParentNode()
                spawnedNodeArray.removeAtIndex(0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: SCNActionRepeat] [image: SCNActionMove]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out how to stop the retain cycles.

I had to give the action a key so then instead of removing all actions I'm only removing the action for key.

Example:

```
node.runAction(..., forKey: "moveAction")
```

and

```
node.removeActionForKey("moveAction")
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to the question you asked but...

How about keeping a pool of reusable nodes? Instead of removing the node when it's time to die, set its `hidden` property to `true` and add it to a reuse queue. Instead of always creating a new node, first try to dequeue an existing node.

Comment: Great suggestion, I will give this a try. Thanks!